# How use image/svg+xml in JMeter

Tags: svg, jmeter

please support...

How use Request URL in Jmeter (with no protocol): **data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E**

Thank you...

> [Image1: Source method GET svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtKcz.png)
>
> [Image2: How can I remove protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLQdq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This situation is not possible for normal load testing. It looks like you just pasted the `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E` line into browser URL.

This doesn't generate any [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) therefore it does not test anything apart from your browser's ability to support [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Assuming all above there is nothing to do with JMeter here.

---

Going forward when it comes to [web applications load testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) you don't need to either manually create requests for images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. or record them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as real browsers handle it differently.

1. While recording make sure to exclude all the images (including SVG)

   [image]
2. While replaying make sure your HTTP Requests samplers are configured to `Download Embedded Resources` and do it in parallel. This can be done using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

   [image]

Check out [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for comprehensive information on simulating browser's behavior more closely when it comes to web applications performance testing.

Comment: data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E use when display Submit button

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBwoA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqrdL.png

Answer (score 0):

data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E use when display Submit button

[svg tag validate submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBwoA.png)

[svg tag allow display Submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqrdL.png)